# Timer on a location Android studio

Tags: android-studio, timer

How to add a timer to a location (latitude, Longitude) in android studio? or fix a time for a location. if not found on that location alarm or send a notification.

Comment: What do you my Android Studio? Are you talking about your app?

Comment: yes i am talking about my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement geofencing using Google Play Location services. Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing) you can see.

All you need to do is set a location (lat, long) and a radius of fence. Once user will be inside that area, you can perform any action you want.

If you want to do a task at a specific time you need to use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html).

Comment: dear i have implemented all geofencing functions. geofencing just works with location. i want to add time with it as well. any clue for that?

Comment: What do you mean by time? Like at a specific time or a specified time on a specific location?

Comment: If you want to do a task at a specific time you need to use AlarmManager. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Just added a tutorial.

Comment: thanx alot dear i will check it out.